# I'm trying to build a testimony slider with a fade out transition when switching from one testimony to the next using opacity

Tags: javascript, html, css

The slider works fine; the testimonial changes with a click of the left or right chevron arrow buttons. But I want to make it so that when I click the right or left arrow, it does a fade-out into a fade-in transition into the next testimonial by means of opacity. As you can see that is what I attempted to do on the second script, but it didn't work. I'm not sure why it is not working, any help would be appreciated.

```css
.testimonial {
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  max-width: 800px;
  max-height: 800px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-end;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 2;
}

.testimonial span {
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #fff;
}

.testimonial q {
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #fff;
}

.testimonial img {
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.left {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  bottom: 120px;
  right: 370px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}

.right {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  bottom: 120px;
  left: 370px;
}

.testimonials h1 {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 35px;
  text-align: center;
  top: 90px;
  color: #fff;
}

.testimonials {
  position: relative;
  background-image: url('https://get.wallhere.com/photo/nature-mountain-top-Mount-Everest-landscape-1420401.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  font-size: 10px;
  color: #000;
}

.testimonials::before {
  content: "";
  background-image: linear-gradient(35deg, darkgrey, darkslategrey);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.testimonialImg img {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 140px;
  top: 0px;
  left: 160px;
}

.testimonialImg h1 {
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
}

.chevron img {
  filter: invert(1);
}

.testimonial4 img {
  background: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.testimonial1 img {
  padding: 0px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.testimonial3 img {
  padding: 0px;
}

.testimonial2 img {
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="testimonials">
    <div class="testimonialImg">
      <h1>Testimonials</h1>
      <img src="https://www.clker.com/cliparts/H/d/M/E/8/M/white-underline-hi.png">
    </div>
    <div class="testimonial testimonial1">
      <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/a1/c9/af/a1c9af575b575995647b6deeb431387a.jpg"><br>
      <span>Albert Einstein</span> <br>
      <q>We cannot solve our problems with the same thinking we used when we created them.</q>
    </div>
    <div class="testimonial testimonial2">
      <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/236x/56/e3/8f/56e38fe68b8b26d9ecf6bee9850a524e--nelson-mandela-line-drawings.jpg"><br>
      <span>Nelson Mandela</span> <br>
      <q>I learned that courage was not the absence of fear, but the triumph over it. The brave man is not he who does not feel afraid, but he who conquers that fear.</q>
    </div>
    <div class="testimonial testimonial3">
      <img src="https://www.prosportstickers.com/product_images/g/abe_lincoln_decal__43877.jpg"> <br>
      <span>Abraham Lincoln</span> <br>
      <q>You cannot escape the responsibility of tomorrow by evading it today.</q>
    </div>
    <div class="testimonial testimonial4">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/1c/Martin_Luther_King%2C_Jr_.svg/860px-Martin_Luther_King%2C_Jr_.svg.png"><br>
      <span>Martin Luther King Jr</span> <br>
      <q>Faith is taking the first step even when you don't see the whole staircase.</q>
    </div>
    <div class="chevron">
      <img src="https://pp.netclipart.com/pp/s/336-3364252_rounded-arrow-png-rounded-left-arrow-icon.png" class="left" onclick="nextSlide(-1);" onclick="navClickTransition(0);">
      <img src="https://n6-img-fp.akamaized.net/free-icon/right-black-arrow_318-33109.jpg?size=338c&ext=jpg" class="right" onclick="nextSlide(1);" ; onclick="navClickTransition(0);">
    </div>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var slide_index = 1;
    displaySlides(slide_index);

    function nextSlide(n) {
      displaySlides(slide_index += n);
    }

    function currentSlide(n) {
      displaySlides(slide_index = n);
    }

    function displaySlides(n) {
      var i;
      var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("testimonial");
      if (n > slides.length) {
        slide_index = 1
      }
      if (n < 1) {
        slide_index = slides.length
      }
      for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        slides[i].style.display = "none";
      }
      slides[slide_index - 1].style.display = "block";
    }
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function navClickTransition() {
      const navClick = document.getElementsByClassName("testimonial");
      navClick.style.opacity = 1;
    }
  </script>

</html>
```

Comment: Please update your question with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) demonstrating the problem, ideally a runnable one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do))

Comment: It should be updated. The main thing that I want to achieve is to have it fade-out when i click either right or left arrow and fade-in into the next quote. I said that they were testimonials but they are actually quotes.....

Answer (score 0):

It was quite alright, however you missed a couple of steps in the animation process, here is a modified version of your code, I explained everything in comments.

Edited version whit fade out and fade in animations:

```css
.testimonial {
      position: relative;
      top: 0px;
      max-width: 800px;
      max-height: 800px;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: flex-end;
      flex-direction: column;
      text-align: center;
      line-height: 2;
    }

    .active{
      opacity: 0;
      animation-name: fadeIn;
      animation-duration: 1s;
      animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    }
    
    .inactive{
      opacity: 0;
      animation-name: fadeOut;
      animation-duration: 1s;
      animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    }

    .testimonial span {
      font-weight: 500;
      font-size: 25px;
      color: #fff;
    }

    .testimonial q {
      font-size: 22px;
      color: #fff;
    }

    .testimonial img {
      padding-right: 10px;
      padding-left: 10px;
      width: 100px;
      border-radius: 50%;
    }

    .left {
      position: absolute;
      cursor: pointer;
      bottom: 120px;
      right: 370px;
      width: 30px;
      height: 30px;
    }

    .right {
      cursor: pointer;
      position: absolute;
      width: 30px;
      height: 30px;
      bottom: 120px;
      left: 370px;
    }

    .testimonials h1 {
      position: relative;
      font-size: 35px;
      text-align: center;
      top: 90px;
      color: #fff;
    }

    .testimonials {
      position: relative;
      background-image: url('https://get.wallhere.com/photo/nature-mountain-top-Mount-Everest-landscape-1420401.jpg');
      background-size: cover;
      font-size: 10px;
      color: #000;
    }

    .testimonials::before {
      content: "";
      background-image: linear-gradient(35deg, darkgrey, darkslategrey);
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0px;
      right: 0px;
      bottom: 0px;
      left: 0px;
      opacity: 0.8;
    }

    .testimonialImg img {
      position: relative;
      text-align: center;
      max-width: 140px;
      top: 0px;
      left: 160px;
    }

    .testimonialImg h1 {
      position: relative;
      top: 0px;
    }

    .chevron img {
      filter: invert(1);
    }

    .testimonial4 img {
      background: white;
      border-radius: 50%;
      padding-top: 20px;
      padding-bottom: 20px;
    }

    .testimonial1 img {
      padding: 0px;
      background: white;
      border-radius: 50%;
    }

    .testimonial3 img {
      padding: 0px;
    }

    .testimonial2 img {
      padding: 0px;
    }

    @keyframes fadeIn {
      from{opacity: 0}
      to{opacity: 1}
    }
    
    @keyframes fadeOut {
      from{opacity: 1}
      from:{opacity: 0}
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">

    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
      <title>Document</title>
    </head>

    <body>
      <div class="testimonials">
        <div class="testimonialImg">
          <h1>Testimonials</h1>
          <img src="https://www.clker.com/cliparts/H/d/M/E/8/M/white-underline-hi.png">
        </div>
        <div class="testimonial testimonial1">
          <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/a1/c9/af/a1c9af575b575995647b6deeb431387a.jpg"><br>
          <span>Albert Einstein</span> <br>
          <q>We cannot solve our problems with the same thinking we used when we created them.</q>
        </div>
        <div class="testimonial testimonial2">
          <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/236x/56/e3/8f/56e38fe68b8b26d9ecf6bee9850a524e--nelson-mandela-line-drawings.jpg"><br>
          <span>Nelson Mandela</span> <br>
          <q>I learned that courage was not the absence of fear, but the triumph over it. The brave man is not he who does not feel afraid, but he who conquers that fear.</q>
        </div>
        <div class="testimonial testimonial3">
          <img src="https://www.prosportstickers.com/product_images/g/abe_lincoln_decal__43877.jpg"> <br>
          <span>Abraham Lincoln</span> <br>
          <q>You cannot escape the responsibility of tomorrow by evading it today.</q>
        </div>
        <div class="testimonial testimonial4">
          <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/1c/Martin_Luther_King%2C_Jr_.svg/860px-Martin_Luther_King%2C_Jr_.svg.png"><br>
          <span>Martin Luther King Jr</span> <br>
          <q>Faith is taking the first step even when you don't see the whole staircase.</q>
        </div>
        <div class="chevron">
          <!-- you cant really have two onclick listeners, call the transition in the nextSlide instead -->
          <img src="https://pp.netclipart.com/pp/s/336-3364252_rounded-arrow-png-rounded-left-arrow-icon.png" class="left" onclick="nextSlide(-1);">
          <img src="https://n6-img-fp.akamaized.net/free-icon/right-black-arrow_318-33109.jpg?size=338c&ext=jpg" class="right" onclick="nextSlide(1);">
        </div>
      </div>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        var slide_index = 1;
        displaySlides(slide_index);

        function nextSlide(n) {
          displaySlides(slide_index += n);
        }

        function currentSlide(n) {
          displaySlides(slide_index = n);
        }
        
        // you can pass the testemonial index to shorten your array
        // tip: I would really use an id for the index not a class hece you wont have another testemonial w/ the same index
        function navClickTransition(index) {
          const navClick =          document.getElementsByClassName("testimonial"+index);
          // navClick is an array it does not have a style property
          //navClick.style.opacity = 1;
          // this is more like it, however you still not animating the stuff just setting the opacity to 1
          for (let i = 0; i < navClick.length; i++){
            navClick[i].style.opacity = 0;
            
          }
        }
        // in the end you don't even need this function
        
        // for the animation I would use a css animation whit a separate class that you can add to the testemonals on demand
        function displaySlides(n) {
          var i;
          var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("testimonial");
          var current;
          
          for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
            if (slides[i].style.display != "none") 
                current = slides[i];
          }

          if (n > slides.length) {
            slide_index = 1
          }
          if (n < 1) {
            slide_index = slides.length
          }
          
          // switches the animation classes you'll find inactive under active in the css
          current.classList.remove("active");
          current.classList.add("inactive");
          
          // waits for a sec to let the animation finish before loading the next testemonial
          setTimeout(() => {
            for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
              // you'll find the active class under the testemonial calss and the kexframes at the end of the css 
              slides[i].classList.remove("active", "inactive");
              slides[i].style.display = "none";
            }
          
                        slides[slide_index - 1].classList.remove("inactive");
            slides[slide_index - 1].style.display = "block";
            slides[slide_index - 1].classList.add("active");
          }, 1000) // 1s is the animation hence we time out for 1000 mils 

        }
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That is a fade in transition, if you need it I can show you a fade out one too.

Comment: Yes, that would be nice.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean when you say navClick isn't an array. I thought you could select the class name using javascript and change its style properties if it is also in the style.css file.

Comment: You can however you can give multiple elements the same class name, that means when you want to find it javascript won't know which one do you want to find so it returns all in an array. I you want to get only the first of that class you can use `document.querySelector('.classname')` and then you won't need the foreach.

Comment: I have added the fade out transition as you asked.

Comment: Got it. The fadeOut animation isn't working the way I want it to. I added the inactive class in the html file just like you did with the active class, but Im not sure what to do.

Comment: Oh no I see the problem, it has not saved the html that I've made...a sec